# Spring Controller + Thymeleaf form generated by foreach (cannot get access to variables)

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

In thymeleaf I generate "order book" with offers. It is being generated with another controller but I works fine. All data is being printed correctly. The problem is when I want to make an order. In @Controller I am not able to see variables from form. Here is a part of code of thymeleaf

```
<tr th:each="cruise : ${cruises}">
    <form method="post" th:action="@{/makeOrder}" th:object="${cruise}" name="formOrder" modelAttribute="cruise">
        <td><span th:text="${cruise.nameOfCruise}" th:field="${cruise.nameOfCruise}"> nameOfCruise </span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${cruise.id}" th:field="${cruise.id}"> id </span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${cruise.date}"> date </span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${cruise.cost}"> cost </span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${cruise.route.startPlace}"> start </span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${cruise.route.finishPlace}"> finish </span></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <span> Interested? </span>
                <input type="submit" value="order">
        </td>
    </form>
</tr>
```

I try to PostMapping method

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/makeOrder")
public String order(@ModelAttribute Cruise cruise, Model model){
        logger.info(cruise.getNameOfCruise); //NULL
        if(cruise == null) //NOT NULL. It doesn't execute
            logger.info("Cruise is null); 
        ...
}
```

I tried that way, but it had no other effect

```java
public String order(@ModelAttribute("cruise") Cruise cruise, Model model)
```

Entity class

```java
package com.zak.cruise.entity;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cruise")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Cruise {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "idcruise")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name_of_cruise")
    private String nameOfCruise;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private LocalDate date;

    @Column(name = "time")
    private Time time;

    @Column(name = "cost")
    private int cost;

    @Column(name = "number_of_seats")
    private int numberOfSeats;

    @Column(name = "duration")
    private int duration;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "route_id_route")
    private Route route;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ship_id_ship")
    private Ship ship;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    public Cruise() {
    }

    public Cruise(String nameOfCruise, LocalDate date, Time time, int cost, int numberOfSeats, int duration, Route route, Ship ship, String description) {
        this.nameOfCruise = nameOfCruise;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.numberOfSeats = numberOfSeats;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.route = route;
        this.ship = ship;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**WHAT IS IMPORANT**
cruise is NOT NULL any time and it's entity class.
Everything I want to get known is how to extract variables from form to work with them.
I count on your help, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf only does rendering, it does not magically add more data to form post over basic html. As such, a span element is not posted, only input elements are posted to controller.

So you'd either have to change all the span elements to input, or you can add a hidden input with the id value and get the corresponding Cruise object from database in the controller

Comment: It was answer I needed. Thank you a lot! Everything works fine